# How do I set more than one index for a table in a doctrine 2 entity file (using annotations)?

Tags: php, doctrine, annotations, indexing, doctrine-orm

I have two columns representing a start date and an end date.
If I wanted to create a joint index for them, I would do:

```
* @Table(name="concerts", indexes={@Index(name="concert_dates", columns={"date_start","date_end"})})
```

But how would I do an index for each of them ?
Is the following way correct?

```
* @Table(name="concerts", indexes={@Index(name="concert_date_start", columns={"date_start"}), @Index(name="concert_date_end", columns={"date_end"})})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-table) says that `indexes` is an array of `@Index` annotations. So I'd say yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it works fine for me. I have done this:

```
/**
 * Class ProductDisplayArea
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_display_area", indexes={
 *      @Index(name="product_display_area_product_id", columns={"product_id"}),
 *      @Index(name="product_display_area_productCat_id", columns={"productCat_id"}),
 *      @Index(name="product_display_area_productSCat_id", columns={"productSCat_id"}),
 *      @Index(name="product_display_area_productSSCat_id", columns={"productSSCat_id"})
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Admin\AdminBundle\Entity\ProductDisplayAreaRepository")
 */
```